# Security - Run apps with other users

Tags: linux, security, fedora

OS: Fedora 14 i386

It's used as a ""normal desktop laptop"".

"USER A" - it's the mainly used user, i log in with GDM with it, etc.

Goal: I need a little more security - separate a few apps!

How: run 3 applications ( Transmission, Google Chrome, Wine ) with other users ( so not with "USER A" ). But when i'm logged in ( in GUI ) with "USER A", i need icons on he's the Desktop. E.g.: just one click ( without asking for password!! ) and Google Chrome starts with another user.

How exactly can i do this? - How can i "grant" "USER A" with permissions ( securely ) so that it doesn't needs a password, when running applications with "USER B", "USER C", etc.?

Are there any howtos/docs/links?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/242264/security-run-apps-with-other-users).

Comment: Can you clarify why the sudo answer below didn't work?  Are you having trouble figuring out how to use sudo?  Is the question how to automate setting up sudo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 Edit sudoers: # visudo

```
...
user1  ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/transmission, /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

2 Add launch button for call "gksu -u user2 /usr/bin/transmission", "gksu -u user2 /usr/bin/chromium-browser"

Comment: thank you very much, but theres no gksu, or kdesu under Fedora 14:(

Comment: Does 'gnome-sudo' exist?  Just replace 'gksu' with 'gnome-sudo' if it does...

Comment: Or just add "sudo /usr/bin/transmission" as application to your Desktop (manually) - for chromium the same.